# Selenium Chrome browser on ssh

Tags: python, selenium, ssh, chromium

I'm trying to start a selenium driver on my raspberry pi. If I run the code on my raspi normally it works and the browser starts. But when I start the script via ssh, it doesn't work.

```
chromedriver -v
```

returns `ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.141`

And Chromium is in version 84.0.4147.105-rpt3

The error I get is

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn\'t exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\n\n'
```

Does anyone of you have an idea, on what to do here? I don't really know why it is not working...

Greetings
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify -X to your ssh command to enable X forwarding when you connect from your client, e.g. ssh -X myserver.

Chrome is failing to start as there's no X11 display to show the GUI.